# How to combine ejb and spring transactions

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ejb

Comrades, help.

There is a spring bean into which several ejb beans are injected, each ejb bean executes its own business logic and is marked inside `@TransactionAttribute (TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) from javax.ejb`, respectively.

The questions are:

First one: Is it possible in a spring bean to combine all ejb beans into one method under one spring transaction?

Second one: Will it work as a distributed transaction (if the transaction of some ejb-bean falls off, the transaction in the spring bean will also fall off)?

Comment: Only if you use a `JtaTransactionManager` if you use a local transaction manager it won't work.

Comment: Yes, I use JtaTransactionManager, then the @transactional annotation should work correctly?